# Question about calculus and real analysis

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $x_n = \frac{p_n}{q_n} $ be asequence of rational numbers where $p_n$ and $q_n$  are coprime. Suppose also that $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = x $. $(x_n \neq x)$ Can we conclude that, therefore,

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} q_n  = \infty $$

???

Comment: there seems to be a missing hypothesis. Otherwise, the sequence $x_n = 3/7$ works and obviously $7$ doesn't converge to $\infty$

Comment: Hello, I am sorry I forgot to add the hypothesis that $x_n \neq x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may assume $q_n>0$. Suppose that $q_n\le M$. If $x_m\ne x_n$ then
$$
\Bigl|\frac{p_m}{q_m}-\frac{p_n}{q_n}\Bigr|=\frac{|p_m\,q_n-p_n\,q_m|}{q_n\,q_m}\ge\frac{1}{M^2}.
$$
This implies that $\{x_n\}$ is no a Cauchy sequence, and hence does not converge.

Comment: why do you have ethat $|p_mq_n - p_nq_m| \geq 1 ? $ how did you obtain this bound?

Comment: It is non-zero integer.

Comment: yes! you are right. Sorry, this was an stupid question. Thank you very much for your help!